# jpa repository - mysql : issue while retrieving date value

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have this query :

```
@Query( "Select batchPassage from BatchPassage batchPassage " +
            "where batchPassage.batch.id = ?1 " +
            "order by batchPassage.dateDernierPassage desc")
```

called like that :

```
List<BatchPassage> derniersBatchPassages = batchPassageRepository.findLastBatchPassageForBatchId(batch.getId());
```

In the result, all **dateDernierPassage** date values have one hour more than in the database.
Value in database :

[image]

Value in java :

[image]

If anyone has an idea...

Comment: most likely timezone problem. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-time-instants.html

Comment: correct, timezone settings in java were not good.